# SAXParseException working with GraphMLReader of Prefuse

Tags: xml, utf-8, saxparser, invalid-characters, prefuse

I'm doing a program in Java that uses the prefuse library. The program generates graphs from information collected from twitter. I'm trying to make my program to save the generated graphs so later I can load them.

The prefuse class GraphMLWriter works fine and it generates a graphml encoded in UTF-8 and xml version: 1.0.

My problem appears when I want to load the generated graphml file. To do that I use the method readGraph(InputStream is) of the class GraphMLReader. This method return a Graph object and use a SaxParser to parse the graphml file with a handler object of the class GraphMLHandler. This object constructs the graph as de parser parse all the lines of the xml file. I'm getting a SAXParseException throwed by  prefuse.data.io.DataIOException when the xml file has characters like 'á' or 'ñ' or emoticons. All the xml files generated contains Strings that represent tweets.

An example is:

```
<data key="info">Las extra&#241;o muchooooo a ambas! &#55357;&#56469;</data>
```

The error says:

> Exception in thread "main" prefuse.data.io.DataIOException: >org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 165; columnNumber: 67; The character reference "&#

and nothing else, it seems that the error message is cut.

These is the code that I use to save a graph object 'g' into and GraphML called "Saved graph":

```
(new GraphMLWriter()).writeGraph(graph, "Graph saved");
```

And these is the one wich I use to load the graph into a graph 'g2' generated from a GraphML file called "Graph saved"

```
Graph g2 = (new GraphMLReader().readGraph("Graph saved"));
```

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Characters like 'á' or 'ñ' (= &#241;) seemed to work when I tested.
&#55357;&#56469; are causing problems in SAX (not prefuse).

Comment: Yeah you are right, I had not noticed that. Thanks. When I generate the graph in the moment (recovering Twitter information), I show the tweets with a JPopUpMenu and it recognice emoticons. So how can I put the emoticon in the graphML file so later, when I load the graph,  show it?

Answer (score 0):

`&#55357` and `&#56469` are surrogate parts, so I'm guessing your original data contains some extended unicode characters. It appears that the prefuse `GraphMLWriter` creates an XMLWriter that makes some assumptions about encodings [that aren't necessarily correct](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse/blob/master/src/prefuse/util/io/XMLWriter.java#L407) - it assumes that all characters in a String are 16 bit code points and encodes them accordingly. In this case we appear to have a surrogate pair and some smarter handling is required (to be fair to the original author, seeing such values in the wild in 2005/2006 was somewhat unusual, and pretty much everyone assumed that Unicode meant 16 bits per character).

Regardless, I think the only options you have here are to pre-filter your data, or patch the prefuse library. If you adverse to forking, one approach would be to extend `GraphMLWriter` and override `writeGraph` with an almost exact copy substituting the creation of `XMLWriter` on [line 73](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse/blob/master/src/prefuse/data/io/GraphMLWriter.java#L73) with the creation of your own extended `XMLWriter` in which you override [`escapeString`](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse/blob/master/src/prefuse/util/io/XMLWriter.java#L397) to deal with the surrogates properly. Java's Character class provides methods that tell you if a [char is a surrogate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSurrogate-char-), and if a [pair of a characters make a valid surrogate pair](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSurrogatePair-char-char-) - if you find such a pair you can then generate the correct XML entity.